# C#: How can I access a child classs using a reference to the parent class?

Tags: c#

So I have an abstract class called `Item`, and inheriting from it is a class called `Food`, as well as other classes that can also be considered items such as weapons and clothing.

I'm trying to give npcs in a game I'm working on the ability to cycle through their inventory (`List<Item>`) in order to find food to eat, but they won't be able to eat something unless they know it's food and not a sword or a hat.

So I guess something like `if (inventory[i].GetType () == Food)` would tell them if it's edible, but how do I obtain the reference to the instance of the Food class now that I made sure it was food? Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code instead of a verbal description? This makes it far easiert for us to understand what you´re doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A performant way to do both (checking and getting the typed reference) at a time is by using the `as` operator:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var food = item as Food;
    if (food != null)
    {
         // do whatever special things can be done with food, e.g. add an "Eat" item to some context menu
    }
}
```

Still, a probably better way to achieve this would be by taking advantage of polymorphism.
Staying with the context menu example, your `Item` base class would have to have a virtual method such as `AddMenuItems`, and that method is invoked on every one of your items.

The `Food` class could then override that method to add an "Eat" item to the menu that other types of items do not have.

Answer (score 3):

Let `Food` implement `IEatable`. Then use `items.OfType<IEatable>()`:

```
foreach (var eatableThing in allItems.OfType<IEatable>())
{
    playerChar.Eat(eatableThing);
}
```

Comment: Unless there are non-food items that can also be eaten (indeed possible!), having an additional `IEatable` interface rather than directly using `OfType<Food>` might be a bit of an overcomplication, though.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: maybe `Food` should also be an abstract class and `Egg` or `Bread` would be a concrete one that inherits it. But all are `IEatable` and that matters for OP (_" find food to eat"_).

Comment: If all the item types are hard-coded, yes. If the concrete items are loaded e.g. from resource files and the hard-coded distinctions are limited to a very basic set of attributes (such as is or is not food), a minuscule class hierarchy without any additional interfaces might be the best way to go. It depends a lot on all the factors the OP (rightly, because it is not the central subject of the question) does not tell us about.

Comment: Why should something that is eatable eat itself? I suppose the NPC should eat the `IEatable`, shouldn´t he? Anyway I agree this is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: maybe it should be the player-character that eat it. But since i don't have the char instance here i just said `eatableThing.Eat();`. So maybe this was better: `char.Eat(eatableThing);`

Answer (score 2):

You can check like so:

```
if (inventory[i] is Food)
{
   ...
}
```

The above will return true if the object is `Food` or a subclass of `Food`.

Then you can just cast it and call its method:

```
Food food = (Food)inventory[i];
food.Eat();
```

Comment: With the new roslyn features you can actual do `if (inventory[i] is Food food)` at which point the variable food will be populated

Comment: I believe that's C# 7 and above, iirc. If OP is using Unity3D then it's likely not available, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @SwiftingDuster you can use whatever version you like in unity, just like creating a normal c# project.

Answer (score 2):

If Item has a property called IsEdible then all other items in the inventory would have to implement it, but of course, only Food returns true.

```
interface IItem
{
      bool IsEdible {get;}
}

class Food : IItem
{
    public bool IsEdible => true;
    public void Eat();
}

class Gun : IItem
{
      public bool IsEdible => false;
}


...
{
   IItem item = ...
   if(item.IsEdible)
   {
       Food food = (Food)item;
       food.Eat();
   }
}
```

I would also comment that this sort of breaks OOP idioms a bit as you shouldn't have to do the cast to a concrete type.  The `interface` functions should be used if at all possible.

Comment: Keeping IsEdiable in a seperate interface called IEatable would be better than implementing it directly to IItem

Comment: @VimalCK: That depends *a lot* on what the OP is doing. Littering the codebase with dozens of small interfaces is not necessarily any better than keeping everything in one rigid class, for example. And if the OP's game distinguishes a couple of items that have only a few basic properties (with the concrete items such as bread, rice, meat, etc. possibly not being hard-coded, anyway, but loaded dynamically from settings or resource files), then having the relevant distinguishing properties such as `IsEdible` right on the general `IItem` interface can arguably be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the object to the specific type! There are two possibilities to do this

- either a direct cast, for example: `var f = (Food)o;`
- or the [`as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) operator and check if the object is null or not

So in your case:

- `var f = (Food)inventory[i];`
- or as in the response of O.R.Mapper `var food = item as Food;`

Answer (score 0):

If You're using C# in version 7 or later (7.1, 7.2 as for the date), You can use the new pattern matching feature to make Your code a bit more elegant:

```
public class Item { }
public class Food : Item
{
    public void Eat() { }
}
public class Clothes : Item
{
    public void Wear() {}
}

public void DecideWhatToDo(Item item)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case Food f:
            f.Eat();
            break;
        case Clothes c:
            c.Wear();
            break;
    }
}
```

You may also have a generic filtering for Your items:

```
public List<T> Filter<T>(this List<Item> items) where T : Item
{
    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    foreach(var item in items)
        switch (item)
        {
            case T i:
               result.Add(i);
               break;
        }

     return result;
}
```

And then You go like: `items.Filter<Food>()` and You have the result filtered and casted to the desired type.

Yet another approach, which avoids casting and reflection would be to model Your items to provide list of accepted usages:

```
//can be a class as well if You need it to be
public interface Item 
{
    List<Usage> PossibleUsages {get;}
    void Do(Usage whatToDo)     
}

public enum Usage
{ Eat, Drink, Wear, ThrowAway }

public class Food : Item
{
    public List<Usage> PossibleUsages
    {
        get => new List<Usage> { Usage.Eat }
    }

    public void Do(Usage whatToDo)
    {
        switch(whatToDo)
        {
            case Usage.Eat: Eat(); break;
            default: throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported action", nameof(whatToDo));
        }       
    }

    private void Eat()
    {
        //Your stuff
    }
}
```